# I would like you to pay attention

Tags: grammar, politeness

I sent an email including a sentence like,
“I would like you to pay attention...” I know the proper usage should be like “I would like to draw your attention” but I am just wondering if the way of expressing is polite or not? Or Did I make a mistake?

Comment: What is the other context? Is it like: "I would like you to pay attention to the recent poll" or is it something else?

Comment: What I would like you to pay attention to is that there might be some inconsistent data types...you may find the content of the data as follows...

Comment: It may help you to see that *like you to pay* says what **I should do**, and *like to draw your attention* says what **you want to do**. By itself, telling me to pay attention says directly that I am not paying attention (Thanks). But you can politely focus me with *Please pay special attention to the format*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say that we would like a naughty child or inattentive subordinate to "pay attention" to something. A native speaker would very likely find it rude. On the other hand, it is polite to say "I would like to draw your attention to" something.

Comment: Then I made a mistake :// I hate Monday’s

Comment: You hate **Mondays** (no apostrophe).

Comment: I'd say "There are several very important points to the PM's Covid instructions. In particular, I would like you to pay attention to ...' is far less pedantic than "I would like you to pay attention."